# Overwrite firestore field after 5 minutes of no update

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, settimeout

I am displaying cards that hold data from Google firestore. One of the fields is "Status". The Status can get turned on and off remotely from outside the app. I would like the Status to automatically turn to "Off'  after 5 minutes or after 5 minutes of no updates to the document.

I would like to do this in the case a user loses connection and can no longer send the "Status": "Off" message. I don't want the card to just say "On" forever.

I am using Vue.js and have tried some various things but I am not quite sure how to accomplish this. I apologize if this question would be better suited for a different site. I have looked up similar questions but couldn't find anything.

Here is a screenshot to visualize what I am asking. I want the Status to turn to "Off" if not updated within 5 minutes. Or any amount of time.

[image]

[image]

[image: DB]

```
<div >
    <div class="ma-4">
        <div  centered class="text-lg-center headline"> 
            Live Middleware Status 
            <p v-bind="allig">{{ seconds }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

        <v-card  slow v-bind="allig" :class="`mx-4 my-4 ${user.Status}`" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
          <v-card-title flat class="pa-n3">
            <v-flex class="mx-auto" xs6 sm4 md2 lg2>
              <div class="caption grey--text">Location Site ID</div>
              <div class="title">{{user.id}}</div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex class="mr-auto " xs6 sm4 md2 lg2>
              <div class="caption grey--text">ID</div>
              <div class=" ml-n12 title">{{user.CustomerID}}</div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex style :class="`mx-auto ${user.Status}`" xs6 sm4 md2 lg2>
              <div class="caption grey--text">Current Status</div>
              <div class="status title mx-2">{{user.Status}}</div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex style class="mx-auto caption green--text" xs6 sm4 md2 lg2>
              <div class="caption grey--text">Last Message</div>
              <div class="Green my-2 title">{{user.TimeStamp}}</div>
            </v-flex>
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>

      </div>
      </template>


      <script>
// eslint-disable-next-line
import firestore from "firestore";
// eslint-disable-next-line
import db from "@/components/fbInit";
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  components: { },
  data() {
    return {
      wide: false,
      ToggleDelete: false,
      card: true,
      light: true,

      seconds: "",

      users: [],

      links: [{ route: "/logs" }]

    };
  },

  created() {

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var employeeRef = db
      .collection("userProfiles")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("MX")
      .orderBy("TimeStamp", "desc")

    employeeRef.onSnapshot(snap => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log(snap.size);
      this.users = [];
      snap.forEach(doc => {
        const data = 
        {
          id: doc.id,
          Name: doc.data().Name,
          GroupHex: doc.data().GroupHex,
          DeviceType: doc.data().DeviceType,
          UserIDInt: doc.data().UserIDInt,
          CustomerID: doc.data().CustomerID,
          SiteID: doc.data().SiteID,
          SuperID: doc.data().SuperID,
          Status: doc.data().Status,
          TimeStamp: doc.data().TimeStamp,
          Original: doc.data().Original
          };
        this.users.push(data);
      });
    });
  },

  methods: {   }

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this reliably, you will need to have a server-side process periodically checking and updating documents. A straightforward way would be to use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). It would look something like this:

```
// functions/index.js

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.updateIdle = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun(async () => {
  const snap = await db.collection("MX")
    .where("Status", "=", "On")
    .where("Timestamp", "<", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 5 * 60000))
    .get();

  await Promise.all(snap.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({Status: 'Off'})));
});
```

The above function will run every minute, look for any documents that have a timestamp from more than five minutes ago, and update each of those documents to have an `"Off"` status.

This is just an example, you might need to do it a little differently for your specific needs.

Comment: Okay thanks! This definitely gives me some direction. Would this be better than doing something on the app that triggers a write operation to firestore after some period of time?

Comment: This would be more reliable because it will work even if the user goes away and closes the browser tab (something that seems pretty likely if you're looking for some kind of "idle timeout" functionality).

Comment: My database is organized with userProfiles>One doc per user>4 subcollections per doc. I am trying to implement this and I am wondering if I have to use wildcards to detect which doc changes or what I am doing wrong. It says I need to create an index but I already have. I updated pic of database in post for reference. Thanks